# How to restart the program? (Restart button in game)

Tags: java

I am making a game and when you loose there is a `Play Again` button. I'd like to when you hit that have the game totally start over. It may seem like a basic question but it's within a class and it's not at the end of the program so it can't just be one big while to go back to the top. Any ideas?

Comment: 1. This cannot be said without a code. 2. You do need to provide some kind of a global loop.

Comment: @Beginner what do you mean? There is no global loop. The only looping thing is the run class which handles calling other classes and running some things. I don't want to post my whole code. I don't know what code you would require as there is not much other then that run class that deals with looping.

Comment: @Fogest Without seeing the code it will be very hard to help you.

Comment: @Fogest what is the first method that you call in the run/main method?
Call that method, maybe?

Comment: @Mr1159pm yeah I could, but... that would mean that all variables and GFX drawings are not reset unless I added that all.

Answer (score 2):

If you have some function to initialize all the things that need initializing (for instance, take the contents of your constructor and put it in an init() function), then the "Play Again" button can just call init() to reset everything.

Comment: I'm quite new I don't have a full understanding of constructors but the only thing I think may have one is the class dealing with GFX and this would be it `public void paintComponent(Graphics g)`. If that is what your talking about how would you go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a method that you call at the beginning of the game?
Add action listener to the play again button and from that action listener call that method.
I am just guessing here...

Comment: `public class draw extends JPanel implements KeyListener,MouseListener{` That is my class. What actionlistener would I be adding to it?

Comment: You said in your question that you have a big button at the end of the game. Add action listener to that button then from the method action preformed call your start method (or whatever it's called).

Comment: Oh it's not a swing button it's a button made in photoshop and when clicked in the specific area of the image it is suppose to restart.